# How would I append items to a list, use that information, clear the list, and then use it again?

Tags: python, list, random, append, list-comprehension

This is just a part of the code that I am using to try to make a game sort of like yahtzee. It probably looks a little rough (this is my first project since finishing the codeacademy course).

What I need to do is put the number between 1-6 randomly chosen associated with each dice into a list that I can work with to eventually decide if the numbers are 3 of a kind, four of a kind and so on.

I just need a simple way to work with the numbers in the list and then after they choose to roll again I can erase the numbers and add new random numbers to the list.

```
 dice_1 = random.randrange(1,7)
 dice_2 = random.randrange(1,7)
 dice_3 = random.randrange(1,7)
 dice_4 = random.randrange(1,7)
 dice_5 = random.randrange(1,7)

 dice_list = []

 def roll_dice(): #adds random number of dice to dice_list
     dice_list.append(dice_1)
     dice_list.append(dice_2)
     dice_list.append(dice_3)
     dice_list.append(dice_4)
     dice_list.append(dice_5)

 def choice():
     player_turn = 1
     while player_turn <= 3:
        roll_again = raw_input("Would you like to roll again? (yes or no)")
        if len(roll_again) == 3:
            del dice_list[0:len(dice_list)]
            roll_dice()  #Find out how to delete what was already in that list and exchange it with the new numbers
            dice_pics()
            break
            player_turn += 1
        elif len(roll_again) == 2:
            read_dice()
            break
        else:
            print "That was not a yes or no answer! Try again!"
```

`

Answer (score 0):

'Emptying' out the list is as simple as `any_list = []`.

Comment: Ok but after I empty it how do I get my dice to have get a new random number and append that back to the list?

Comment: @LexiMarieReicks how did you get it in there in the first place?

Comment: I appended the numbers into the list. Now what I want to do is ask the user if they want to roll again. If they do I need to delete the numbers in the list and add a new set of random numbers. Can you look at my choice function and tell me what I am doing wrong? @LeeDanielCrocker

Answer (score 0):

Python is a garbage-collected language. It does memory management for you. So fill a list with five random dice:

```
a = [random.randrange(1,7) for x in range(5)]
```

then just

```
a = []
```

to clear it, then fill it again, as often as needed. What this actually does is assign the name "a" to a newly-created empty list. The old list that a pointed to is now no longer referenced, so it will be collected.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of it that way.

Comment: Codeacademy: worth every penny. :-)